# kubernetes.default: Name does not resolve

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, openshift-origin

Im running OpenShift.

- OpenShift Master: v3.3.1.7
- Kubernetes Master: v1.3.0+52492b4

But am having problems trying to run a build in Jenkins (running in a pod). This is not a problem with the java code that I'm trying to build, but is a problem in the Kubernetes/Openshift setup.

The builds fail with:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default: Name does not resolve
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    ...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: So.. you verified that the host name can be resolved via DNS?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - how do I do that?

Comment: Can you share your code? The error clearly states a DNS problem, so there seems to be some host name involved that cannot be resolved.

Comment: Which code would you like me to share? I dont think this is a problem with the code that I'm trying build in Jenkins, but a configuration problem in OpenShift / Kubernetes.

Comment: might be a good idea to run a kubectl get pods --namespace kubesystem. If kube-proxy has problems, your whole networking (internal *and* external) will be in trouble

Comment: Would be interesting to learn whether you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that DNS is actually working with:

```
› kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never 
Waiting for pod default/busybox to be running, status is Pending, pod ready: false
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    192.168.60.10
Address 1: 192.168.60.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 192.168.60.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

If that doesn't work check if the DNS pods are running:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```

Will respond sth like:

```
NAME                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-dns-v14-3u5zi   3/3       Running   36         166d
```

Finally checking the related logs is worth a try:

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kube-dns
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c dnsmasq
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c healthz
```

Full instructions can be found on [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/dns/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check on manage jenkins -> Configure Global Security  -> Agent port is 50000 and Fixed