# Jenkins With Rancher-Kubernetes Set up

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, rancher

My current set up has Rancher Labs v1.6.10 and I have set up a Kubernetes Cluster with 1 Master and 2 Agents.
I have deployed Jenkins-Master Instance in Kubernetes and I am able to access it.Installed Kubernetes plugin in jenkins to dynamically spin up the slave agents. However, I am not able to connect to the Kubernetes cluster in any way -

I have tried giving the rancher url
   https://10.17X.XXX.XXX/r/projects/1a353/kubernetes:6443

But it gives java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)

Any idea what URL I should give & this URL is not accessible?

Ideally if all this cluster is up, any pod in any node should be able to communicate with the other.

Comment: not sure about Rancher, but when I configured Jenkins on Kubernetes I've configured the plugin with the service domain name: `https://kubernetes.default`

Comment: For me it gives  java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc error if I use the default url.

Answer (score 0):

[kubernetes.default: Name does not resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655458/kubernetes-default-name-does-not-resolve)

This post helped solve the issue. kube-dns pod was not up in my case. On bringing that up, dns name was resolvable & I was able to access kubernetes cluster with https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local