# service names resolve on master but not other nodes

Tags: dns, kubernetes, virtual-machine, virtualbox, kube-dns

Following [DNS troubleshooting instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/), service names resolve on the master node's pods, but not on slave node's pod.
I have a 2-node kubeadm cluster setup on VirtualBox CentOS VM's with flannel.

from master:

```
kubectl exec -ti etcd-master -n kube-system -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    192.168.1.1
Address 1: 192.168.1.1

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 92.242.140.21 unallocated.barefruit.co.uk
```

from slave:

```
 kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
command terminated with exit code 1
```

This issue is [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805483/kubernetes-pods-cant-resolve-hostnames?rq=1#comment78682406_45805483), by @P.J.Meisch, but no resolution since it wasn't the actual question.

The /etc/resolv.conf on each of the nodes (VM's) just has my host machine IP as the nameserver. is this wrong?

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fios-router.home
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Is flannel a bad choice for this set up?

Comment: Flannel is ok and has no influence on that issue. I suggest setting up a dedicated name server with debug enabled, and then provide here logs for further inspection.

Comment: Thanks for flannel info @d0bry How do i set up a nameserver? Is this in kubernetes?

Comment: @d0bry can you advise on the way to make a nameserver for VMs and kubernetes?

Comment: do you have kubedns running? Please chck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655458/kubernetes-default-name-does-not-resolve if this helps